# bash interactive script pass input

Tags: bash, command-line-arguments

I'm running the following interactive Jar.

```
java -jar script.jar
  argument-line-here
  \n
```

Now I'm creating a bash script which runs the jar file.
How do I pass the argument line and the conformation "\n" to this interactive script? these are input lines for the script.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392525/passing-arguments-to-an-interactive-script-non-interactively) has some answers, `expect` is not yet installed on my system and i do not have sudo.

edit: The .jar also doesn't return any text. it only expects 2 lines. (one with arguments and one with a conformation enter).
I also cannot edit the Java application. It is not my script. If I could've I would've.

Things I have tried but didn't work.

```
java -jar myscript.jar
<<< &"argument1 argument2 argument3 argument4" <<< $"\n"
```

and

```
java -jar java -jar myscript.jar > tmp.txt 
expect ""
send "argument1 argument2 argument3 argument4"
expect ""
send "\n"
```

Comment: the thing is. I cannot edit the source code of this Java application. I only got the jar.

Comment: What the answer in the linked duplicate tells you (you *did* read it?) is that you just pass the arguments as normally, like any other command.

Comment: Yes, I have tried this. `java -jar myscript.jar argument1 argument2 argument3 argument4` (also with and without \n in the end. but the result is the same. the application is still waiting for input

Comment: Ah, then your question is ***not*** about "arguments", but about normal input. I'll post an answer.

Comment: You have a point there, the word arguments is a bit confusing here. will edit the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect the normal standard input of the program, you could use so called "here documents" (see e.g. [the BASH manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/bash.1.html)):

```
java -jar script.jar <<EOF
your input here
EOF
```

That means standard input (a.k.a. `stdin`) is redirected and will be the text in the "here document", in this case `your input here`.

Comment: How to specify value for password string. I mean for inputs when console.readPassword() is called.