# Ansible - Control commands when need users input when executing

Tags: ansible

How can i control user inputs when a command is executing and ask me something 
for example :

```
sudo apt-get install mariadb-server
```

when you run this command in ubuntu it asked you please enter new password for mysql user root and then again it ask to enter password again for confirmation .
how can i pass a variable for example mariadbpass to this command because everytime ansible run this hangs and failed so i have to login to servers and run manually this

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

to enter prompted password and its confirmation.

thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is the Solution : 
add this before installing mariadb 10 task in your playbook

```
- name: debconf asking for password
  debconf:
   name: maria-db-10.0
   question: "{{ item }}"
   vtype: password
   value: "{{ mariadb_root_password }}"
  with_items:
   - mysql-server/root_password
   - mysql-server/root_password_again
```

Comment: This does not help for the question in the title, for non-`debconf` issues... (i.e. password prompts)

Answer (score 2):

This is less of an ansible question and really a bash question.  I'd suggest you take a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392525/passing-arguments-to-an-interactive-script-non-interactively) and tie some of those into your playbook to do what you need.

The easiest for you in this case, is likely using a [here string](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Here-Strings)

```
tasks:
  - shell: "apt-get install mariadb-server <<< $'password\otherprompts\n'"
    sudo: true
```

Comment: i found another answer that is using debconf module in ansible if i success with debconf i will write it down here