# Is there a way to input automatically when running a script?

Tags: shell, ubuntu, psql

I am trying to execute a script file which asks for password as input. Is there any way we give the command the input it needs automatically?
It's in psql which has parameter `-U` for username but no parameter for password.

Example:

```
exa00009@exa00009:~$ sh redshift.sh
Password for user xyz:
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [passing arguments to an interactive program non interactively](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392525/passing-arguments-to-an-interactive-program-non-interactively)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can provide command line argument for your script like below:
`sh redshift.sh yourInput`
and in your script get it as `var input=$1` and use accordingly.

This question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6405127/how-do-i-specify-a-password-to-psql-non-interactively)

Comment: can u elaborate , my .sh file has psql command which excepts username parameter but not password . i need to automate it so that i just have to run script

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`expect`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect) for this.
Here is simple example:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
set PASSWORD "1"
set USER "dvp"
spawn psql -U ${USER} -W
expect "*?assword*"
send -- "${PASSWORD}\r"
expect eof
```

Probably you need to install `expect` first:

```
sudo apt-get install expect
```