# Cannot configure code with echo in docker with alpine os but can in ubuntu

Tags: docker, ubuntu, alpine-linux

I have a Dockerfile which was originally pulling from ubuntu and I recently came across alpine which is more lightweight so would like to pull from that instead. Part of the code I'm trying to build is called [Healpix](https://healpix.jpl.nasa.gov/) which depends on [cfitsio](https://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/fitsio/). When I originally built the ubuntu version I found this Dockerfile https://github.com/MilesCranmer/dockers/blob/master/dockerfiles/healpix.

Essentially the problem is the following works in ubuntu but not with alpine:

```
RUN echo "3\ngfortran\n\nY\n\n\ngcc\n\n\n\n\nN\n1\nY\nN\nN\n0\n" |
    ./configure && make
```

The error I get is

```
Something went wrong ...
Quitting configuration script !

./configure: exit: line 162: Illegal number: -1
The command '/bin/sh -c echo     "3\ngfortran\n\nY\n\n\ngcc\n\n\n\n\nN\n1\nY\nN\nN\n0\n" | ./configure     && make' returned a non-zero code: 2
```

somewhat confusingly the configure script in question isn't 162 lines long https://sourceforge.net/p/healpix/code/HEAD/tree/branches/branch_v350r1006/configure. I have tried installing bash and changing script to that but that didn't work.

#### ubuntu Dockerfile

```
FROM ubuntu
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y gcc g++ gfortran make wget
WORKDIR /home
RUN wget \ 
   http://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/FTP/software/fitsio/c/cfitsio_latest.tar.gz \
   && tar xzf cfitsio_latest.tar.gz
WORKDIR cfitsio
RUN ./configure --prefix=/usr && make && make install
WORKDIR /home
RUN wget \
   https://sourceforge.net/projects/healpix/files/Healpix_3.50/Healpix_3.50_2018Dec10.tar.gz \
   && tar xzf Healpix*.tar.gz
WORKDIR Healpix_3.50
RUN echo \
    "3\ngfortran\n\nY\n\n\ngcc\n\n\n\n\nN\n1\nY\nN\nN\n0\n" | ./configure \
    && make
```

#### alpine Dockerfile

```
FROM alpine
RUN apk --no-cache add gcc g++ gfortran make wget
WORKDIR /home
RUN wget \ 
   http://heasarc.gsfc.nasa.gov/FTP/software/fitsio/c/cfitsio_latest.tar.gz \
   && tar xzf cfitsio_latest.tar.gz
WORKDIR cfitsio
RUN ./configure --prefix=/usr && make && make install
WORKDIR /home
RUN wget \
   https://sourceforge.net/projects/healpix/files/Healpix_3.50/Healpix_3.50_2018Dec10.tar.gz \
   && tar xzf Healpix*.tar.gz
WORKDIR Healpix_3.50
RUN echo \
    "3\ngfortran\n\nY\n\n\ngcc\n\n\n\n\nN\n1\nY\nN\nN\n0\n" | ./configure \
    && make
```

Comment: Have you checked the `./configure` script line 162 (where the error comes from)? Could you edit your question and post this script (at least the part returning the error)?

Comment: @norbjd have edited the question

Comment: I think the main problem here is the way you are passing arguments to your `./configure` script. You should use one of the solutions presented in that answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/14397049 instead.

Comment: will try but just curious why it works on ubuntu/macos like how I have it above though ^

Comment: The only difference I see is the shell used : to execute the script (see the shebang at the top of `./configure`), alpine uses `/bin/sh` -> `/bin/busybox`, while ubuntu uses `/bin/sh` -> `/bin/dash`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### TL;DR

In your `Dockerfile`, use :

```
RUN /bin/echo -e "3\ngfortran\n[...]" | ./configure && make
```

to have the same behavior on Ubuntu and Alpine.

#### Explanations

The `./configure` script is executed with `/bin/sh` (see the shebang). On Ubuntu, `/bin/sh` is a link to `/bin/dash`, while on Alpine, `/bin/sh` is a link to `/bin/busybox`.

The following small example reproduces your problem.

Consider the following `./configure` script :

```
#!/bin/sh

read -p "1st prompt : " first
read -p "2nd prompt : " second

echo "$first-$second"
```

On Ubuntu :

```
docker run --rm -v $PWD/configure:/configure ubuntu:18.04 \
    /bin/sh -c 'echo "a\nb" | ./configure'
```

prints :

> a-b

While, on Alpine :

```
docker run --rm -v $PWD/configure:/configure alpine:3.8 \
    /bin/sh -c 'echo "a\nb" | ./configure'
```

prints :

> anb-

On Alpine (`busybox`), the `echo`ed string (`a\nb`) is interpreted as a single argument, while on Ubuntu (`dash`), the `\n` is used to separate both arguments.

To have the same behavior as Ubuntu on Alpine, you can run :

```
docker run --rm -v $PWD/configure:/configure alpine:3.8 /bin/sh -c 'echo "a                   
b                                                 
" | ./configure'
```

or :

```
docker run --rm -v $PWD/configure:/configure alpine:3.8 /bin/sh -c \
    'echo -e "a\nb" | ./configure'
```

(see the `-e` parameter of `echo`)

These 2 commands print :

> a-b

As for your `Dockerfile`, you should write something like :

```
RUN /bin/echo -e "3\ngfortran\n[...]" | ./configure && make
```

`/bin/echo` is used instead of `echo` because on Ubuntu, `echo -e "3\ngfortran\n[...]"` will print `-e 3\nngfortran\n[...]`.

> This is because `echo` is parsed a shell built-in, while `/bin/echo` is explicitly not (source : https://github.com/moby/moby/issues/8949#issuecomment-61682684).