# How do I pass a script to Sage before running it in interactive mode?

Tags: python, interactive, sage

In my Python workflow, I commonly use the `-i` flag to open a Python interpreter which first executes the script I am working on, then allows me to interact with it. For example, in `test.py`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
print("Hello World")
x=2
```

When I run `python -i test.py` from the command line, I receive the following output:

```
Hello World!
>>>
```

Interactive mode is enabled, yet all definitions made in the script are available to me. Typing `x` will yield `2`.

Is there an analogous process for Sagemath? I have tried the `-c` flag, but the command `sage -c "attach('test.sage')"` fails to enter interactive mode after loading the module I am working on.

Ideally there would be a solution simpler that the one outlined [which uses `expect`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14397442/1438723), but if that is indeed the best solution, how would one go about using `expect` to cause Sagemath to start an interactive session after loading a specific file?

Answer (score 2):

There is a startup file you can make called `init.sage` for every interactive Sage session.  See [this FAQ](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/faq/faq-usage.html#can-i-make-sage-automatically-execute-commands-on-startup) and [this documentation](http://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/reference/repl/startup.html#the-init-sage-script).  Is that what you are looking for?  You are right that `sage -c` only computes.

Answer (score 0):

The Sage runtime generates for your sage script a Python script with the Sage wrapper. For example, you have *script.sage.py* generated from *script.sage*.

In the interactive mode of Sage which runs a customized IPython interpreter (see [Sage Interactive shell](https://doc.sagemath.org/html/en/tutorial/interactive_shell.html)), you can the Python script with

```
sage: %run script.sage.py
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure that you can pass it before, but you can still do it within  sage console.

```
sage: load("<path-file>")
```