# Option selection in dockerfile/shell command

Tags: docker, shell, terminal

I am building a dockerfile that following commands:

```
RUN sudo apt-get install python-pip -y && \
    pip install --upgrade pip && \
    pip install qibuild 

RUN qibuild config --wizard -1 -2
```

Now in qibuild wizard. I have following:

```
qibuild config --wizard
Found CMake: /usr/local/bin/cmake
:: Please choose a generator
   1 Unix Makefiles     (default)
   2 Ninja
   3 CodeBlocks - Ninja
   4 CodeBlocks - Unix Makefiles
   5 Eclipse CDT4 - Ninja
   6 Eclipse CDT4 - Unix Makefiles
   7 KDevelop3
   8 KDevelop3 - Unix Makefiles
   9 Sublime Text 2 - Ninja
   10 Sublime Text 2 - Unix Makefiles
> 1
:: Please choose an IDE
   1 None   (default)
   2 QtCreator
   3 Eclipse CDT
> 2
:: Found QtCreator: /usr/bin/qtcreator
:: Do you want to use qtcreator from /usr/bin/qtcreator?
Answer 'no' if you installed qtcreator from Nokia's installer (Y/n)
> Y
```

I want to make selection 1,2 and Y from dockerfile only.

I have already tried:
qibuild config --wizard -1 as well as
qibuild config --wizard &&1

But docker script fails at selection. How to I make such selection?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing arguments to an interactive program non-interactively](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14392525/passing-arguments-to-an-interactive-program-non-interactively)

Comment: No, I am trying with CMD command instead of run

Comment: `RUN printf "%s\n" "1" "2" "Y" | qibuild config --wizard -1 -2`

Comment: @KamilCuk 
Your command did do something but I am not sure if it selected them or not


printf "%s\n" "1" "2" "Y" | qibuild config --wizard
Found CMake: /usr/local/bin/cmake
:: Please choose a generator
   1 Unix Makefiles  (default)
> :: Please choose an IDE
   1 None  (default)
   2 QtCreator
   3 Eclipse CDT
> :: Found QtCreator: /usr/bin/qtcreator
:: Do you want to use qtcreator from /usr/bin/qtcreator?
Answer 'no' if you installed qtcreator from Nokia's installer (Y/n)